# Permission automatically resets to root after using chown

Tags: permissions, samba, chown, root-filesystem

I've got a samba shared directory which previously was setup normally but I noticed not being able to connect to it anymore. Turns out that permissions were reset to root and whenever I try to change it either with `nautilus` or with `chown sambauser:sambashare directory` it instantly resets permissions to `root:root`

**What's happening here and how do I change it?**

The directory path is `/sharing/` and the permissions I want to set are `sambauser:sambashare`, it is also the samba server having this problem, not a samba client.

My only guess is that it might be due to the root-filesystem that the directory is inside, but that's only a guess.

Comment: How do you mount the directory?

Comment: I use automount like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416638/how-do-i-automount-a-hard-drive-to-samba-using-autofs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the way I setup the automount options.

I simply added uid and gid to my configuration and it worked again.
It used root because it was inside the root filesystem, since nothing else was provided. Telling the configuration which user and group to use made it accessible by said user or group. Always nice to solve my own problems after enough digging.